# NSArray of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` which is coming from server as `JSON` format. I want to add one more `NSDictinoary` to the `NSarray` of `NSdictionaries`. `Nsdictionary` is based on key value pair. This is the response which I am getting. I want to add another dictionary of same format into "table". Pls Help..

Thanks in advance..!!

```
Table =     (
                {
            Name = “xyz”;
            Recordid = 3;
            prefrenceorder = 1;
        },
                {
            Name = “ABC”;
            Recordid = 2;
            prefrenceorder = 2;
        },
                {
            Name = “swe”;
            Recordid = 450;
            prefrenceorder = 3;
        },
                {
            Name = “asd”;
            Recordid = 451;
            prefrenceorder = 4;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Approved.  Go ahead.

Comment: @trojanfoe pls lemme know how to go ahead. I am confused.!!

Comment: Oh, you wanted someone to write it for you?  That's not how it works here.  If you don't know how to do it and you don't know how to search the internet, then you are out of luck.

Comment: nsarrays are immutable, so you will have to create a new nsarray combining the dictionaries coming from server and your own dictionary

Comment: @trojanfoe I din't wanted anyone to write it for me. Just wanted to know whats the approach for doing this. Anyways Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

As the NSArray coming from server is immutable so you need to create a new instance of NSMutableArray to add your own dictionary with the response coming from server.

```
NSMutableArray *newTable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:Table];
[newTable addObject:your_new_dictionary];
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `NSDictionary`'s into a `NSMutableArray`. And then from your instance add your new object `NSDictionary`

i.e

```
//The array which has your NSDictionary objects
NSArray *array;

//Putting this array into mutable one in order to add and delete elements
NSMutableArray *mArray = [array mutableCopy];

//Your custom object that you want to add
NSDictionary *yourObject;

//Add it to the array and voila
[mArray addObject:yourObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to convert immutable array to a mutable but to use appropriate NSJSONSerialization option - [NSJSONReadingMutableContainers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSJSONReadingOptions)

> Specifies that arrays and dictionaries are created as mutable objects.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
[mutableArray addObject:yourNewDictionary];
```